# having trouble accessing mysql database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've just started with mysql.
I created a database "`practice`" and a table named "`student info`"(i am using `XAMPP` as local server).
I was successfully able to connect my sql to the server but i am unable to perform any query .
the error recieved is

> Table practice.studentinfo doesn't exist

Here is the code....

connecting to server

```
<?php
$host='127.0.0.1';
$user='root';
$pass='1234';
$db='practice';

if($link= mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db)) 
{
    echo "connected successfully";
}

?>
```

performing query

```
<?php
include('db_connection.php');
$table="studentinfo";

$query =" SELECT 'name' from $table ";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
if(false===$result)
{
    printf("error: %s\n",mysqli_error($link));
}

?>
```

output:

> connected successfully error: Table 'practice.studentinfo' doesn't
>   exist

kindly help!!!!

Comment: Did you try performing the query from console?

Comment: Does the table have any columns?

Comment: Double-check that you connected to the MySQL instance you think you are connected to. Try running the query "SHOW TABLES" and see what it returns.

Comment: Don't you have table name **student info** (with space)? If yes please try `$table="student info";` and in query: `$query =" SELECT 'name' from '$table' ";`

Comment: @sebast26, table names and column names should be delimited by back-ticks. Single-quotes are for string literals and date literals. `$query =" SELECT \`name\` from \`$table\` ";`

Comment: You say 'a table named "student info"' - does it really have a space or some sort of separator?  Because the table you are trying to open doesn't have one.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for the solution. Worked like a charm for me.It was a syntactical error as i was using Single-quotes instead of back-ticks.

Comment: @sebast26 thanks for pointing that out. I wasnt providing any space between student and info.

Comment: @Steve^ you too